# Are there any tools to automate software installations?

Tags: windows, installation, automation

I was wondering if there are any tools to automate installation of software on computers. What I have in mind is to place the installers in a Folder and kind of record their installation once. Later I want to be able to just copy the installer folder and playback the recorded steps so they are automatically installed. This will save me huge amount of time also ideally I would want some tool which is smart enough to open console etc and type commands which are required during some installations.

Is anyone aware of any tool like this?

Thanks

Comment: The idea came to me while installing Node JS and its components, Imagine I have to install Node JS, then Grunt, then SASS, Compass and rest of the packages manually. Why Can't I simply create an installer to do all this work for me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are tools such as Chef, Ansible, Puppet which manage installations like this through Powershell, I know Chef has Windows Powershell support but whether it will solve your specific use case is down to exactly what you need to have done.

Comment: Thank you Voycey for you answer, all these tools look good but they seem like for enterprise use, and must be very expensive. Are there any tools that are free or maybe do not cost much that you are aware of?

Comment: They are all Open Source tools and therefore mostly "Free"